TypeError in calling static method by call_user_func
I can call directly response::error(...$args) in PHP 8.2.
But calling via call_user_func() occurs this TypeError :
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class "response" not found

My code:
print_r($method); // Array ( [0] => 'response', [1] => 'error' )
print_r($args); // Array ( [0] => 404 )

call_user_func($method, ...$args); // TypeError!
call_user_func($method[0].'::'. $method[1], ...$args); // TypeError!
call_user_func($method, $args); // TypeError!
call_user_func($method[0].'::'. $method[1], $args); // TypeError!

response::error(...$args); // OK!


response is probably not its fully qualified name. Did you use something or are you in a namespace?

thanks @tkausl , your comment solved the problem. :)

I renamed response to xresponse and the problem solved!
I found that my code was in a namespace that contains response class.
So calling response::error has not problem.
But calling via call_user_func() needs the namespace in method name.
$method[0] = 'NameSpace\' . $method[0]; // fix the class name.
call_user_func($method, ...$args); // OK!

